# $X_n\leq Y_n \implies \inf X_n \leq \inf Y_n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, supremum-and-infimum

$x_n\leq y_n\ \forall n \in N \implies \inf x_n \leq \inf y_n$

It is obvious from the definition of infimum and supremum, $\sup x_n \leq y_n$ and $\inf x_n \leq x_n \leq y_n$. However I do not know how to use the definition to prove formally that $\sup x_n \leq \inf y_n$ and conclude that
$\inf x_n \leq \sup y_n$.

Comment: $\sup x_n \le \inf y_n$ does not hold. Try some sequences with $x_n = y_n$.

Comment: I would be careful with your statement.  It is true that if $x_{n} \leq c$ for some fixed real number $c$, then $\sup x_{n} \leq c$ as well.  But if you are comparing a sequence $x_{n}$ to another sequence $y_{n}$ and find that $x_{n} \leq y_{n}$ for all $n$, that doesn't mean $\sup x_{n} \leq y_{n}$.  The left hand side of the inequality is a fixed number, but which $n$ are you choosing for the right hand side?  Here is an example: Take $x_{n} = 1 - \frac{2}{n}$ and $y_{n} = 1 - \frac{1}{n}$.  Clealry, $x_{n} \leq y_{n}$ for all $n$.  But $\sup \{x_{n}\} = 1$ which is bigger than all $y_{n}$.

Comment: It is not true that $\sup x_n \leq y_n$ and the sequences $x_n = 1/(n+1)$ and $y_n=1/n$ show for the left hand side is $1/2$ and the right hand side, when $n = 3$ is $1/3.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
$$
\inf x_n\leq x_n\le y_n
$$
for all $n$. So $\inf x_n$ is a lower bound for $y_n$ whence
$$
\inf x_n\leq \inf y_n.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Assume by contradiction $$\inf x_n=x>\inf y_n=y$$therefore$$\forall 0<\epsilon <x-y,\exists 
 N\qquad \forall n>N\to 0\le y_n-y<\epsilon<x-y$$which means that the exists $n\in \Bbb N$ such that $$y\le y_n<x\le x_n$$or equivalently $$y_n<x_n$$which is a contradiction. Therefore $x\le y$ and the proof is complete $\blacksquare$